# If $a \sin(\phi) + b \sin(\theta) = c = a \cos(\phi) +b$, then prove $\cos{\left(\frac{\phi-\theta}{2}\right)} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2c^2-(a-b)^2}{4ab}}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $a \sin(\phi) + b \sin(\theta) = c$ and $a \cos(\phi) +b = c$. Then prove the following holds:
>
> $$\cos{\left(\frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\right)} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2c^2 - (a-b)^2}{4ab}}$$

Can somebody give a hint in the easiest way possible? I am trying to prove this for hours and can't get the idea. **My attempt** : $a\sin \phi + b \sin \theta = a \cos \phi+b$ or $a(\sin \phi- \cos \phi)=b(1-\sin \theta)$

Comment: This Q is hard to read. Hence, consider to visit [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for format improvement.

Comment: As [user317176's answer](/a/4800233) indicates, what you're asking to prove is not true in general. Nonetheless, my [answer](/a/4800241) shows that by changing $b$ to $b\cos(\theta)$ in your second equation, it does work properly. Please check whether or not my suggested change is correct. If so, then please edit your question with the correction, and let me know so I can then update my answer accordingly.

Comment: One other thing, as I've now also indicated in my answer, there's an implicit requirement in the equation to prove that $ab \neq 0$. Please also check if this was actually explicitly stated with your problem. Regardless, I suggest adding this condition to your question as it's a necessary condition.

Answer (score 2):

As [user317176's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4800233/602049) indicates, the premise is not generally true as currently stated. However, changing the second equation to $a\cos(\phi) + b\color{red}{\cos(\theta)} = c$, along with using the implicit requirement that $ab \neq 0$, does work. In that case, squaring both sides of the $2$ provided equations gives

$$a^2\sin^2(\phi) + 2ab\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) + b^2\sin^2(\theta) = c^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$a^2\cos^2(\phi) + 2ab\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) + b^2\cos^2(\theta) = c^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Adding these $2$ equations together, and using that $\cos(\phi - \theta) = \cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) + \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$, results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^2 + 2ab(\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) + \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)) + b^2 & = 2c^2 \\
2ab + 2ab\cos(\phi - \theta) & = 2c^2 - a^2 + 2ab - b^2 \\
2ab(1 + \cos(\phi - \theta)) & = 2c^2 - (a - b)^2 \\
\frac{1 + \cos(\phi - \theta)}{2} & = \frac{2c^2 - (a - b)^2}{4ab}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, using the half-angle formula for $\cos$ given in [Half-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae), we have

$$\cos{\left(\frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\right)} = \operatorname{sgn}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\right)\right)\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\phi-\theta)}{2}} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Substituting \eqref{eq3A} into the RHS of \eqref{eq4A} above, along with using that $\operatorname{sgn}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\right)\right)$ is more generally $\pm$, we then get what you're asking to prove, i.e.,

$$\cos{\left(\frac{\phi - \theta}{2}\right)} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2c^2 - (a - b)^2}{4ab}} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\theta = \frac {\pi}{2}$ then $\sin\theta = 1$

$a\sin\phi + b = c = a\cos\phi + b\\
\sin\phi = \cos\phi\\
\phi = \frac {\pi}{4}\\
c = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}a + b$

$\cos (-\frac {\pi}{8}) = \sqrt\frac {2(\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}a + b)^2 - (a-b)^2}{4ab}$
$\sqrt\frac {2(\frac {a^2}{2} + ab\sqrt 2 + b^2) - (a^2 + b^2 -2ab)}{4ab}$
$\sqrt\frac {2ab\sqrt 2 + b^2 -2ab}{4ab}$
$\sqrt\frac {2\sqrt 2 + b +2}{4}$

In this case, it must also be that $b = 0$  But, if $b$ is zero then we can't divide by $4ab$

The premise does not appear to be true.